# COmo guardar un archivo PDF que tiene base64 en laravel?

Tags: laravel, reactjs

Desde mi frontend con ReactJS , me llevo un archivo PDF, con base64 , ejemplo , en el body de la peticion , estoy pasando un objeto con la propiedad

{ file1: "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKM ->> es mas largo' },

, en el Backend de laravel quiero procesar este archivo , decodificarlo de base64 y guardarlo en el Storage , pero por mas que lo intento con las soluciones de los foros no condigo la solucion.

cual es la manera mas sencilla y correcta de realizarlo ?

Mi ultima solucion fue esta pero aun asi no me funciono

```
    $files = base64_decode($request['file1']);
    Storage::disk('local')->put('example3.pdf',$other['file1']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una respuesta para una imagen también en base64, lo conclusión es que necesitas remover la primera parte del string: `data:application/pdf;base64,` antes de intentar decodificarlo y guardarlo.

```
// Obtenemos la cadena desde request
$base64_pdf = $request['file1'];
// Sustraemos todos los caracteres que están despues
// de la primera coma ',', excluyendo así el comienzo
// del string
$data = substr($base64_pdf, strpos($base64_pdf, ',') + 1);
// Se decodifica
$data = base64_decode($data);
// Y ahora lo guardamos
Storage::disk('local')->put("example3.pdf", $data);
```

Fuente: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-file-storage-how-to-store-decoded-base64-image